# Powershell function returns intermediate values

Tags: regex, function, powershell

I'm probably misunderstanding how PowerShell functions work, but I have the following to extract the year from a string such as "abcdef20201123xyz":

```
function getYear($str) {
  $str -match ".*(?<year>[\d]{4})[\d]{4}.*"
  return $matches['year']
}
```

I expected `getYear("abcdef20201123xyz")`  just to return "2020", but I get

```
True
2020
```

Why is this, and how do I just get what I put in the "return"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell, every not handled function call is sent to the output. So you either **assign the return value to a variable**, or you **pipe it to Out-Null**:

```
function getYear($str) {
  $str -match ".*(?<year>[\d]{4})[\d]{4}.*" | out-null
  return $matches['year']
}
```

Comment: I'd very strongly encourage `if($str -match $pattern){ return $matches['year'] }`, otherwise you risk getting a match group value from a previous comparison

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen 100% agree.

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen, and this avoids error displays when there is no match. +1